# transitive and intransitive verbs

Tags: verbs, objects

1. **Is it plausible to mainly take account of the image of action that a certain verb gives rather than the usage (transitive or intransitive) of verb when I construct a sentence?**
   Of Course,I'm asking that except for the verbs like be, become and etc.

.

2. In a similar vein, now I ask a detail question. the phrase "lead to" is used like this.

> the situation A leads to a dangerous situation.

**but can I use "lead" and "to" like this?**

> the president leads the situation A to a dangerous situation.

is it wrong?? answer me please.

Comment: Why do you think you are wrong? And at the same time why does it have to be right? Please include in your question the homework/research you have done for it.

Comment: I don't think so. As a learner, my experience shows that learning a language must be done **gradually**, **consistently** and **properly**. You must know which verb is transitive and which one is not and which one is both.

Comment: but when you look into dictionary too many Verbs have both transitive and intransitive usage with similar meaning. I couldn't feel any need to memorize the words' characteristic(transitive or intransitive), as i said above, except for some famous ones like be, become, discuss, marry and etc.

Comment: The state of "being famous" is relative! It depends on how much you use words. For example, If you have to write a book, thesis, etc, then you will need to use a wide range of different verbs with similar meanings. by the way, there are too many, you are right, but we have too much time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your sentence is close to idiomatic. You simply need the progressive/continuous rather than the simple present.

**Failing to clean a cut can *lead to* infection.**

**You can *lead* a horse *to* water, but you cannot make it drink.**

**The mayor *is leading* the city *to* apocalypse and ruin with this new tax on soda pop.**

Comment: Downvoting both question and answer without any explanation is of little value.